# Changing the Application Icon, Splash Screen etc through code in Windows Phone

Tags: windows-phone-7, silverlight-4.0

Is it possible to change Application Icon, Splash screen etc through code, My requirement is i need to change these items after reaching a specific date say (jan-21-2012). Is there any provision present change these contents through code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, you cannot change these through code. These components of your application are specified via the manifest file. Regarding the Application Icon, you can have a 'live tile' for your application which is dynamic and can be changed. See MSDN:

[How to: Create, Delete, and Update Tiles for Windows Phone](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh202979%28v=vs.92%29.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

Maybe this blogpost about the dynamic splashscreen can help you?

http://windowsphonegeek.com/articles/All-about-Splash-Screens-in-WP7-ndash-Creating-animated-Splash-Screen

I don't think you can change the application icon this way. Do you have to change the icons multiple times through the year? Or is it one rebranding action? In that case i would suggest submit it with the new icons/splashscreen to the marketplace when you want it to change.

Answer (score 0):

Here there are couple of articles about changing Splash screen:

- [Creating Animated Splash screen in Windows Phone7](http://www.abhisheksur.com/2011/05/creating-animated-splash-screen-in.html)
- [Windows Phone 7 better Splash screen](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/windows-phone-7/WP7_better_Splash_screen.aspx)

You can extend techincs from articles above and implement your functionality.

Regarding to "Icon" use well known WP feature - Live Tiles (nice links in answers above).